# SQL JOIN INNER or OUTER

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have two tables:
**users**: id username clan
**clans:** id clan crest

I trying to do the search by username with output the clan of username.

Query:

```
SELECT `users`.`id`, `users`.`username`,`users`.`clan`, `clans`.`crest` FROM `users` JOIN `clans` ON `users`.`username` LIKE '%gu%'
```

Output:

```
id  username    clan       crest       
2   gusar                  26_760.gif 
3   gusar11     Tong       26_760.gif
```

If clan is empty crest will be empty.. But ... (

I want following result:

```
id  username    clan       crest       
2   gusar                  
3   gusar11     Tong       26_760.gif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're joining from one table to another using a LIKE, typically there is little reason why you would do this. Instead you likely want that in a WHERE clause, and you should be joining between the table using a foreign key.

You want to use a LEFT OUTER JOIN (or LEFT JOIN for short) to attempt to match all of the rows in the second table, but to show NULL values if there was no match:

```
SELECT `users`.`id`, `users`.`username`,`users`.`clan`, `clans`.`crest`
FROM `users` 
LEFT JOIN `clans` ON `users`.`clan` = `clans`.`clan`
WHERE `users`.`username` LIKE '%gu%'
```

Mind you, in your users table, ideally you should hold the clan id and not the clan title. You would then use this query to perform your search:

```
SELECT `users`.`id`, `users`.`username`,`users`.`clan`, `clans`.`crest`
FROM `users` 
LEFT JOIN `clans` ON `users`.`clanid` = `clans`.`id`
WHERE `users`.`username` LIKE '%gu%'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want results from the first table, even when there are NO matches in the second table, you want to use a LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT `users`.`id`, `users`.`username`,`users`.`clan`, `clans`.`crest` FROM `users` LEFT JOIN `clans` ON `users`.`username` LIKE '%gu%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the table using some condition. You're using an ON where you should use a WHERE. I assume `users`.`clan` relates to `clans`.`clans`? Try this:

```
SELECT `users`.`id`, `users`.`username`,`users`.`clan`, `clans`.`crest` FROM `users` LEFT JOIN `clans` ON `users`.`clan` = `clans`.`clan` WHERE `users`.`username` LIKE '%gu%'
```